Connector identification for Ortur 10W laser module laser-to-adapter-board cable
I have searched for days now and haven't been able to identify this connector. It is from the laser cable of an Ortur 10W laser module. It is 6 pin, 2 row, 2 mm pitch and row spacing. I need to find the correct crimp tin for this connector. I've tried Dupont and JST PH series (SPH-002T and SPH-004T) and neither are correct.  I do not know the model number of the connector.  It was supplied by Ortur.
.

what is the model number  of the connector

Unfortunately, there are no markings on any of the connectors on this board.

Where did you get the connector shown at lower right? Was it supplied by Ortur? Or did you buy it? If you bought it, how do you not know the part number? If supplied by Ortur, have you asked them for the part number for required crimp sockets?

I'm waiting for a response from Ortur. It was supplied by Ortur. Hoping someone knows what it is or can tell me what to search for.

This is called a PHB connector.  It is used mostly in Asia and I was not able to find it from Digikey or Mouser.  These are the resourses I found:
https://www.lcsc.com/products/Housings-Wire-To-Board-Wire-To-Wire_11067.html?keyword=PHB
https://www.aliexpress.com/i/3256804014485813.html?gatewayAdapt=4itemAdapt
Reddit post where I got the answer: https://www.reddit.com/r/AskElectronics/comments/1cp1jx9/please_help_me_identify_this_connector/
